# Filtering json reponse from website API with Python Requests

Tags: python, json, get, python-requests

I need to query a betting exchange webstie using their API. I can get a list of event names and ids with Python Requests using the following code:

```
r15 = s.get('https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events/?sport-ids=24735152712200&category-ids=10812641776701')
data1 = r15.json()
for event in data1['events']:
    print(event['name'])
    print(event['id'])
```

I now know the numbers I need to filter by category-id and sport-id, but I don't know how to filter the json response for just the names of the runners. How do I filter the json reponse with Requests so it only shows me the runners names, and not the entire stream of json data?

An example of a json response for a similar request is given below:

```
<events-response>
<offset>0</offset>
<per-page>1</per-page>
<total>38</total>
<events>
<event>
<id>393986311580028</id>
<name>12:50 Gowran Park</name>
<sport-id>24735152712200</sport-id>
<start>2017-01-26T12:50:00Z</start>
<in-running-flag>false</in-running-flag>
<allow-live-betting>false</allow-live-betting>
<category-id>
<category-id>10812641776701</category-id>
<category-id>24735152712200</category-id>
<category-id>24735153536300</category-id>
<category-id>393798405520028</category-id>
</category-id>
<status>open</status>
<volume>938.65922</volume>
<markets>...</markets>
<meta-tags>
<meta-tag id="10812641776701">
<name>Ireland</name>
<type>COUNTRY</type>
<url-name>ireland</url-name>
</meta-tag>
<meta-tag id="24735152712200">
<name>Horse Racing</name>
<type>SPORT</type>
<url-name>horse-racing</url-name>
</meta-tag>
<meta-tag id="24735153536300">
<name>Gowran Park</name>
<type>LOCATION</type>
<url-name>gowran-park</url-name>
</meta-tag>
<meta-tag id="393798405520028">
<name>2017-01-26</name>
<type>DATE</type>
<url-name>2017-01-26</url-name>
</meta-tag>
</meta-tags>
</event>
</events>
</events-response>
```

an xml example with the same structure as the json response I get (i.e. featuring the 'runners' tag) is given at;

https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events/?sport-ids=24735152712200&category-ids=10812638253700

Comment: You could decode the json string and then select the category-id from the resulting dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events')
data = r.json()
for event in data['events']:
    print(event['category-id'])
```

out:

```
[9, 291015400640036, 380069543210027, 380069652690027]
[110, 291907469820036, 357657110470027]
[10812641776701, 24735152712200, 24735152733701, 393122343520028]
[10812641776701, 24735152712200, 24735152733701, 393122343520028]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24735152714301, 393122343520028]
[10812641776701, 24735152712200, 24735152733701, 393122343520028]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24795683891101, 393122343520028]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24735152714301, 393122343520028]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24735153508400, 393122343520028]
[10812641776701, 24735152712200, 24735152733701, 393122343520028]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24795683891101, 393122343520028]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24735152714301, 393122343520028]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24735153508400, 393122343520028]
[10812641776701, 24735152712200, 24735152733701, 393122343520028]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24795683891101, 393122343520028]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24735152714301, 393122343520028]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24735153508400, 393122343520028]
[10812641776701, 24735152712200, 24735152733701, 393122343520028]
[6, 375895250670027, 392314597880056]
[10812638253700, 24735152712200, 24795683891101, 393122343520028]
```

Comment: ok I'm still having trouble with this - I get an xml response like this: https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events/?sport-ids=24735152712200&category-ids=10812638253700 and I want to navigate to the tag 'runners'. The dict structure doesn't seem to let me do that

Comment: @Davtho1983 this is xml response, not json. use BeautifulSoup or lxml to parse this response, and if you have any question, please post another question and taged with `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear - I mean the structure of the json response is the same as the xml in that it's nested the same.  - it actually looks like this: b'{"offset":0,"per-page":20,"total":24,"events":[{"id":400898325470010,"name":"17:00 Dundalk","sport-id":24735152712200,"start":"2017-02-03T17:00:00.000Z","in-running-flag":false,"allow-live-betting":false,"category-id":[10812641776701,24735152712200,24743063490401,400564059760010],"status":"open","volume":6968.18741,"markets":[{"event-id":400898325470010,"id":400898327610010,"name":"WIN","runners":. ..

Comment: @Davtho1983 post another question, it's hard to answer question in the comment

Comment: Ok sorry I edited this question instead - hopefully by asking the question better the answer will be useful to more people